# Why are images served by Google Appengine's Images API not oriented correctly?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exif

If you create an image using the AppEngine [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/images/)  the output image has no Exif. If the source image has an orientation flag set in the Exif, this is not persisted into the output image and so will appear rotated to a user.

Is there a way to tell the `ImagesServiceFactory` to pass the Exif through to the output image?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found so far is to simply read the Orientation flag using [a java Exif parser](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor), then apply a rotation transform to the generated image so that the pixels are actually rotated. Here's a simplified example:

```
byte[] sourceImage = yourCode();

int orientation = 1;
try {
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(sourceImage));
    orientation = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class).getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    log.log(Level.INFO, "Failed to extract orientation", t);
}

Image destinationImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(sourceImage);
Transform rotate;

switch (orientation) {
    case (EXIF_ORIENTATION_90): {
        rotate = ImagesServiceFactory.makeRotate(90);
        break;
    }
    case (EXIF_ORIENTATION_180): {
        rotate = ImagesServiceFactory.makeRotate(180);
        break;
    }
    case (EXIF_ORIENTATION_270): {
        rotate = ImagesServiceFactory.makeRotate(270);
        break;
    }
    default:
        rotate = ImagesServiceFactory.makeRotate(0); // anything else, no rotate
}
destinationImage = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().applyTransform(rotate, destinationImage);

final byte[] destinationImageData = destinationImage.getImageData();
```

That should be enough to get you going. [Possible Exif orientation values](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) (if present) are:

```
1 = Horizontal (normal) 
2 = Mirror horizontal 
3 = Rotate 180 
4 = Mirror vertical 
5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW 
6 = Rotate 90 CW 
7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW 
8 = Rotate 270 CW
```

I would prefer not to have to do this since it requires an unnecessary transform, and the extra Exif parsing step. Better solutions welcome :)